Can I see fsck.exfat progress info, somehow?
e2fsck supports the -C switch for printing progress information; however - fsck.exfat does not. Is there any way to track its progress externally? perhaps something like a disk map which lights up when a certain physical sector (or set-of-sectors) is read/written?
